# How to prevent sun light from passing through the walls and flickering when navigating in viewport?

Tags: lighting, unreal-5, csg

I am new to UE5. I am using a geometry brush to create an inner box and an outer box. The inner is set to **brush type ‘subtractive’**, resulting in a simple room like this:
[image: Simple room]

Then I create several windows using the same subtractive way:

[image: Windows]

Now the sunlight behaves very weirdly: **it passes through the solid wall** and **flickers** when I navigate or rotate my camera view.

[image: Flickering]

This is absolutely some glitch, but I don’t know how to fix this so that the sun light behaves more stably instead of coming and going unexpectedly when navigating in the room.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this other thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/xotio6/why_doesnt_lumen_work_with_bsp_brushes/), it would appear that Lumen does not work very well with brushes. Most people recommend transforming the brush into a static mesh to avoid this issues.

Alternatively, to quickly create a room you can use the meshes available in the starter content pack. To add the starter pack to an existing project, look at the top left of your Content Browser window and you will see an `Add` button with a green plus icon. Click that and then select `Add Feature or Content Pack...`. This will add to your project a number of things, including some basic meshes to create rooms. You can also get meshes from Quixel Bridge.

Finally, I don't know what the goal of your project is nor am I a professional developer, but from my understanding brush editing (and the Modeling tool) are used to prototype levels to quickly test them or make a proof of concept (PoC). In these scenarios, lighting does not need to be perfect so the behaviour you are seeing would not matter much (though it would of course be incorrect for a shipped game).